# why catch a TimeExpired exception in python subprocess lose stdout?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

app.py

```
import subprocess
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    outs = ''
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'app2.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          text=True)
    
    try:
          p.communicate(timeout=3)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
          p.kill()
          outs, _ = p.communicate()
          print(outs)
```

app2.py

```
import subprocess
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print("counter")
        time.sleep(1)
```

according to doc(https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

> If the process does not terminate after timeout seconds, a TimeoutExpired exception will be raised. Catching this exception and retrying communication will not lose any output.

However running `python3 app.py` actually produce nothing, why?

---

update:

In vscode debug model, the behavior is as expected, output is normal!!
really weird..

Comment: Probably a buffering issue - at 8 characters per second, it's going to take a LONG time to fill up the default noninteractive output buffer size.  Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` to app2.

Comment: @jasonharper,  run `app2.py` directly is ok, the printing is shown every 1sec; is it different between print to the PIPE and the shell terminal? If it takes time to fill the buffer, why in shell terminal it works fine for `app2.py`(run directly)

Comment: If you run a program directly from the shell, its output is normally buffered line by line.  But if you run it in a non-interactive manner, the default is typically 4096 bytes of buffering.  You'd have to wait over 8.5 minutes for app2 to fill that buffer up.